# Problems with std::stoi, was not declared on MinGW GCC 5.1.0

Tags: c++11, gcc, mingw

I tried my code on my computer which is running MinGW GCC 5.1.0.

When I enter :

```
g++ hope.cpp -o hope -I D:\armadillo-7.600.2\include
```

The cmd show me:

```
hope.cpp:183:26: error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope
Point_Num = stoi(temp[1]);//number of point
                      ^
hope.cpp:190:34: error: 'stof' was not declared in this scope
Point(i, 0) = stof(temp[travel]);
```

But when I enter:

```
g++ hope.cpp -o hope -I D:\armadillo-7.600.2\include -std=c++11
```

The cmd show me：

```
C:\Users\von77\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXdhQzS.o:hope.cpp：(.text$_ZN4arma7op_norm21vec_norm_1_direct_stdIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EE[_ZN4arma7op_norm21vec_norm_1_direct_stdIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EE]+0x7b): undefined reference to `dasum_'
C:\Users\von77\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXdhQzS.o:hope.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma7op_norm21vec_norm_2_direct_stdIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EE[_ZN4arma7op_norm21vec_norm_2_direct_stdIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EE]+0x7f): undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
C:\Users\von77\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXdhQzS.o:hope.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma4blas3dotIdEET_yPKS2_S4_[_ZN4arma4blas3dotIdEET_yPKS2_S4_]+0x3f): undefined reference to `ddot_'
C:\Users\von77\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXdhQzS.o:hope.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma6lapack5gesddIdEEvPcPiS3_PT_S3_S5_S5_S3_S5_S3_S5_S3_S3_S3_[_ZN4arma6lapack5gesddIdEEvPcPiS3_PT_S3_S5_S5_S3_S5_S3_S5_S3_S3_S3_]+0x8c): undefined reference to `dgesdd_'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And after I use atoi instead of stoi:
I got the same result as "g++ hope.cpp -o hope -I D:\armadillo-7.600.2\include -std=c++11".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include the string header

```
#include <string>
```

and you need to specify the namespace

```
std::stoi(temp[1]);
```

Comment: I have already done that but the result is the same as before

Comment: The _undefined reference_ error is due to a missing library, you need to specify which one with the -l option I'm guessing you need -larmadillo or -llapack or -lblas

Comment: Have u use the armadillo before？